# Can I find a fully-funded PhD position in europe at 39 or more?

Tags: phd, application, funding, europe

I'm 37 now and hold a master degree. I got my degree 3 years ago. For some personal reasons I plan on applying for a phd position next year or later.( I cannot do that now.)
I love my field and doing research. But I'm extremly worried about that **if it is possible to find a fully-funded phd position in europe at 38 or over.** I know it's possible in the US or Canada. But I'm not sure about europe. I'll appreciate any advice.

Comment: My question became closed because of being strongly depending on individual factors. After closure I edited my question. However it's still closed. I appriciate the only answer I got before closure. But I need more people to give me advice. People with experience similar to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I did my PhD, there were several more mature PhD candidates (I would guess end 40s or 50s). All of them (as far as I know) finished their PhD successfully. So, it is doable. The good thing in academia is that age rarely matters. If you really want to do a PhD, then go for it.

Finding a paid PhD place is a tricky bit. It really depends on the area of research. Engineering and Physics are usually working with industry and have the funding to pay PhD candidates.
I would recommend looking at webpages like: https://www.findaphd.com/

Many universities in the UK (at least) offer studentships; however, you need to apply **before** you start your PhD (usually you apply for both funding and the PhD spot). You won't have the option to apply for funding after you started.

In other countries like Austria and Germany, PhD positions often come with a multi-year long contract and you are getting a salary; however, finding those is not always easy as they are often given to previous students. Again, online research might help.

Personally, I would recommend you do the following:

- Look online, at what areas in your field interest you.
- Then, look at who is doing research in this field/on those topics.
- Then, pick the research groups that are most interesting to you. (Keep an open mind to non-elite universities too. Not every expert sits at the ETH Zurich or Imperial College London).
- (hardest bit) Think of things that interest you within this topic (specifics) and maybe what idea you have that could be researched.
- Finally, contact the head of the research team and ask if they have a project coming up or just express your interest in becoming their PhD student. The lecturers and head of labs have a lot of say in who gets funding.
- (Also, check if the uni of that team offers studentships or vacancies)

Regarding: "is it worth to get a PhD at 45?"
Financially, a PhD is rarely worth it. You won't get a significantly higher salary because of it; however, it will be easier to get a job as you are an expert in whatever you researched. In most cases, a PhD is important to stay in the academia. Anything outside the academia, you can achieve without a PhD.
I know a person, who did a PhD in their 40s and years later ended up becoming a full professor. If you are in it for money, don't do it. It is very demanding. If you in it because you love your field and want to stay in the academia, then go for it.

Comment: I know the application process. I was just worried about my age condition. I found some contradictory information about age limit in european universities. Especially for finding funded positions. I appreciate your encouraging answer.